# How can I use Rails image_url helper on the Controller layer so that it returns the correct value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to call `image_url` (from the `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` module) from within a controller. My controller is an API controller that renders a json response. So, the controller prepares the object and I am using `jBuilder` to render the actual JSON response. Here is the code:

```
class Api::Mobile::HomeController < Api::Mobile::ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

  def index
    @items = [Api::Mobile::HomePageItem.new(
                type: 'image',
                image: image_url("api/mobile/home/tutor-with-student.jpg"))]
  end
end
```

The image `tutor-with-student.jpg` exists in the following folder:

```
app/assets/images/api/mobile/home/tutor-with-student.jpg
```

The problem is that the `image_url` returns the value:

```
http://myhost.com/images/api/mobile/home/tutor-with-student.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://myhost.com/assets/api/mobile/home/tutor-with-student.jpg
```

Note that when I am using the `image_url` from the actual view, the method returns the correct value.

How can I use the `image_url` method on the Controller layer so that it returns the correct value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("api/mobile/home/tutor-with-student.jpg", type: :image)
```

and remove the inclusion of the module
     ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

Also, make sure that you have set the `action_controller.asset_host` value in your environment configuration file. So, for your production environment it should be in `config/environments/production.rb` and it has to be like

```
config.action_controller.asset_host='myhost.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to previous author. I'm not sure about performance but this method helped to me:

```
def logo_url
    host_url = request.path == '/' ? request.url : request.original_url.split(request.path).first
    asset_path = ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url('logo.png')
    host_url + asset_path
end
# will return
=> "http://localhost:3000/assets/logo-40e3bf1e10f0c00393ac94f96ea127986955c166eb839266eb2ad6e63b42754c.png"`
```

Comment: The performance of this method is crazy slow, at least for me.